# How to Java Regex to match everything but specified pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match everything but garbage values in the entire string.The pattern I am trying to use is:

```
    ^.*(?!\w|\s|-|\.|[@:,]).*$
```

I have been testing the pattern on regexPlanet and this seems to be matching the entire string.The input string I was using was:

```
    Vamsi///#k03@g!!!l.com 123**5
```

How can I get it to only match everything but the pattern,I would like to replace any string that matches with an empty space or a special charecter of my choice.

Comment: What do you mean by garbage values?

Comment: Your 'pattern' is weird as well. Also, you need to double escape your patterns in Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pattern, as written, is supposed to match the whole string.

`^` - start of string.
`.*` - zero or more of any character.
`(?!\w|\s|-|\.|[@:,])` - negative look-ahead for some characters.
`.*` - zero or more of any character.
`$` - end of string.

If you only want to match characters which aren't one of the supplied characters, try simply:

```
[^-\w\s.@:,]
```

`[^...]` is a negated character class, it will match any characters not supplied in the brackets. See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for more information.

[Test](http://rubular.com/r/Mpoz8tjSbz).

Comment: thanks for explaining what I was doing wrong...it worked.I had no idea you could put \s \w . and - in [].